# How to use Distinct on a list of object or on one or more properties of the object

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get a list of unique shipping addresses.

```
var shippingAddresses = ShopApi.Checkout.GetShippingAddresses(Shop.CommerceContext.AccountId).ToList();
```

This will give me a list of shipping addresses objects, but two of them have the same value for the **Id** column. How do I filter that or gets only one value to the list?

My **ShippingAddress** object looks like this.

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string CustomerId { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string CountryId { get; set; }
```

Comment: How do you decide which one do you want?

Comment: No need to decide. I just want unique list addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for your situation. You can filter your list again to only get 1 row for each Id value

```
public class ShippingAddresses
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}

List<ShippingAddresses> shippingAddresses = new List<ShippingAddresses>();

//This statement will help you only get 1 row for each ID value
shippingAddresses = shippingAddresses.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(p => p.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in that ShippingAddress object, there is an underlying database query. That query needs to be modified to only include the unique results ... like this:

```
(from dbo in database.ShippingAddress
 select dbo.Id).Distinct()
```

Comment: That I cannot do as the querying part lies in a DLL.